# Missing directory /lib/security causing boot errors

Tags: boot, pam

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 I am getting boot errors as follows:

```
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_deepin_auth.so): /lib/security/pam_deepin_auth.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Sure enough, when I go to see if the files are there, they are not. I tried researching how to install the module (if there is one) that will install that directory and its files. I cannot find that information anywhere.

Tried to install the latest version of `libpam-modules` which is supposed to have the so (shared object) files but it said it was at the highest version already and never added any files to the "service" directory.

I entered the following command:

```
ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/
```

It listed a bunch of `.so` files in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/`, however, the file `pam_deepin_auth.so` does not exist anywhere. I need to know which module contains this file so I can install it. Can't seem to find any module (or package) that contains this file. Why is the system looking for this file if it just doesn't exist in any package?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: @heynnema I never installed anything other than the standard Ubuntu? Not sure what you are referring to. If you believe this is from something non-standard that I may have installed (unintentionally for sure), then how can I find out what that might be. The complaining services are cron, sudo and lightdm (the ones looking for this file). lightdm is also looking pam_kwallet.so

Comment: I suggest a fresh install. It is hard to find what you did with your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no file named pam_deepin_auth.so that is installed by any of the packages in the Ubuntu 20.04 default repositories. You are also not running Deepin, so you don't need the pam_deepin_auth.so file for that reason. Have you installed any software from non-default software sources that contain deepin packages in Ubuntu 20.04?

Maybe you didn't do anything seriously wrong to your system. You can still boot Ubuntu 20.04, so just ignore the boot message that you referred to in the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
After reloading Ubuntu 20.04 from scratch to resolve a different issue, this problem disappeared. Until the next LTS release....